# IBM watson chatbot for facebook messenger

Tags: facebook, ibm-watson, facebook-messenger, watson-assistant

I am trying to implement IBM Watson chatbot into facebook messenger. I am able to verify my webhook. Also, able to receive and send custom messages through facebook to my webhook.

The problem is that i can't receive messages from IBM Watson. IBM Watson is not able to detect my messages and provide appropriate response. Also, can't receive my welcome message from IBM Watson in facebook messenger when chat window is opened. The tutorial which I followed was on youtube and the link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdsjS7ZnPLw

Any suggestion would be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause is not subscribing your webhook to a page after creating it.

The UI doesn't appear until you create your webhook in FB (It's been a year since I have had to do it, so it may have changed).

If that is set up, try connecting to your application layer in postman and make sure you are sending and receiving the right information.

Answer (score 1):

- **Regarding Welcome message:**
  The Welcome node of your dialog is not processed by the Facebook Messenger integration. The welcome message is not displayed in the Facebook chat like it is in the "Try it out" pane or in the Preview Link integration web page. It is not triggered from here because nodes with the welcome special condition are skipped in dialog flows that are started by users. Facebook Messenger waits for the user to initiate the conversation. If you need to set default values for context variables at the start of your conversation, do not set them in the welcome node.
- for more information check: [**Integrating IBM Watson Assistant with Facebook Messenger**](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/487069/full-fledged-watson-assistant-integration-for-test/)